# Ionic serve doesn't run on devApp anymore

Tags: ionic-framework

I used to run `ionic serve` and DevApp would find it on my network. Don't know what I did, but this is not working anymore, when I launch `ionic serve` I have this message:

```sh
[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100
       External: http://192.168.1.67:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process
```

When I used to have:

```
Development server running!
Local: http://localhost:8100
External:

DevApp: demoxv@8100 on PC2
```

Can someone explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got what I changed, I used to run server with my IDE that did the correct command which is:

```sh
ionic serve --devapp
```

That's the command stated in Android DevApp. But in the official Ionic documentation:

[Ionic Documentation: devapp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/running#ionic-devapp)

The command is said to be `ionic serve` without `--devapp`.

Comment: «ionic serve» and «ionic serve -c» does not output «DevApp:» info string, only «Local:» and «External:». How can i get «DevApp:» working? Now i have to enter URL and port manually in DevApp app on my iPhone :(

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late, but for anybody in future it can help.
As I wrote [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3836#issuecomment-562879819) - changing network profile from private to public helped me.
Even if my answer didn't help, the whole topic can be useful.